# Any alternatives to jQuery's slideUp, slideDown, animate functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-dfp

I'm creating a footer ad format to run in Google DFP, but jQuery won't work within it (long story).  So I'm trying to find some alternate ways to accomplish the same tasks - namely the slideUp, slideDown, and animate functions.  Does anyone know of some alternatives?  Thanks!

Comment: If jQuery won't work in it, are there other libraries blocking it? If so, which one(s)?

Comment: by reffering to jquery library, you can prepare your own code for the above functions.

Comment: tiy can try mootools, but the question is why is JQuery not working. Seems like if that isn't working, Mootools also won't

Comment: That was my first post here - great to see so many helpful responses!  Thanks for all the quick help guys!  Correct, I don't think Scriptaculous / Mootools would work either - I'm looking for simple JavaScript functions (already coded b/c I'm not good enough to figure it out myself) I can add to the code rather than pull in dynamically (with a script src tag).  I'd also prefer something small rather than a big JavaScript library like jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link that works with javascript:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-sliding-panels-using-generic-animation

Example:

HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative;
           width:150px;
           height:170px;
           top:0px;
           left:0px;">
  <div id="exampleHeader1" 
      style="position:absolute;
             width:150px;
             height:20px;
             top:0px;
             left:0px;
             background:#3b587a;
             text-align:center;
             color:#FFFFFF;"
      onclick="slideExample1('examplePanel1', this);">
    ^^^
  </div>
  <div id="examplePanel1" 
      style="position:absolute;
             width:150px;
             height:130px;
             top:20px;
             left:0px;
             background:#a6bbcd;
             overflow:hidden;">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function slideExample1(elementId, headerElement)
{
   var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
   if(element.up == null || element.down)
   {
      animate(elementId, 0, 20, 150, 0, 250, null);
      element.up = true;
      element.down = false;
      headerElement.innerHTML = 'vvv';
   }
   else
   {
      animate(elementId, 0, 20, 150, 130, 250, null);
      element.down = true;
      element.up = false;
      headerElement.innerHTML = '^^^';
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thanks!  I'll look into it more closely and give it a go.  Take care,

Comment: It's been over a month, but I finally got to implement this and it works great!  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

[dom-slider](https://github.com/BrentonCozby/dom-slider) is a vanilla-js implementation of jQuery's slideDown, slideUp, and slideToggle methods that works on elements with ***unknown heights***. Use it just like jQuery:

```
element.slideUp()
element.slideDown(800)
element.slideToggle(800, 'easeOut') // CSS transition timing function
element.slideUp(300).slideDown(500)
```

However, its methods don't accept callbacks--instead, you provide the callback with the returned promise:

```
element.slideUp().then(function() {
  console.log('sliding done!');
})
```

There are a few other improvements as well. Check out the [README](https://github.com/BrentonCozby/dom-slider) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives:

1. Scriptaculous has such a thing already to go and has not crashed on pages where I have had conflicts.
2. Mootools.

You can have at some [Scriptaculous demos](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/demos/).

Comment: I'm afraid using another library like this would cause the same problem.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Css animations?
I know, it will jump directly to the end in older browsers (< IE10),
 but still better than nothing and very lightweight.

Comment: I don't know - maybe that would work, but if there are some issues with older browsers like you mentioned, then probably not...

Comment: It's graceful degradation. I mean, it will work everywhere, but in legacy browsers, the animation will jump directly to the end. This won't affect the navigation, but only the "plus value" of having an animation in your navigation. From there, it is your call to determine the importance of the animation :) Hope this help

Comment: Okay, I understand.  Do you have examples of how to do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to achieve? I may be able to help you out with your slideUP and downs/ Alternatively, you can use jquery.animate() to reposition and change heights etc, but slideUp and slideDown do work quite well!

Comment: Hi Shannon, yes, slideUp/Down work great - BUT, jQuery won't work as a src through Google DFP ad server in IE.  It works great in other browsers, and the code itself works find hard-coded to the page in IE, but loading jQuery through Google DFP in an IE browser will not work...  :(  So, I'm looking for alternative individual functions to use.

Answer (score -3):

Just paste the entire jQuery source file into the script you can edit. I'd add probably a 100 or 200 newlines afterwards to add some visual separation from my code.